# What "PAL Shim AllocRequest returning NULL" meens?

Tags: centos6, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

On a HP DL380e Gen8 with Dynamics Smart Array and SAS RAID installed I try to install Centos, after load the RAID Driver from HP Support Site I can access the RAID and do the installation.

The installation works fine and my new Centos Boot on the HP Proliant Server, but when I take a look into the /var/log/messages there is a lot of (>100 per second) this lines in the log file:

```
Dec  9 14:03:27 server01 kernel: PAL Shim AllocRequest returning NULL
Dec  9 14:03:27 server01 kernel: PAL Shim AllocRequest returning NULL
Dec  9 14:03:27 server01 kernel: PAL Shim AllocRequest returning NULL
Dec  9 14:03:27 server01 kernel: PAL Shim AllocRequest returning NULL
Dec  9 14:03:27 server01 kernel: PAL Shim AllocRequest returning NULL
Dec  9 14:03:27 server01 kernel: PAL Shim AllocRequest returning NULL
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from the [Red Hat paywalled support site](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/388943) says:

- Issue: message output "PAL Shim AllocRequest returning NULL" iteratively.
- Environment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4 with HP-tools(third-party package)
- Resolution: Update 'hpvsa' module provided from HP, the above message is suppressed.
- Root Cause: The 'hpvsa' module from HP is an old version.

---

So in this case, I should add that the Dynamic Smart Array controller is not a good solution for most environments. It requires a non-standard driver (compared to the traditional CCISS/HPSA that higher-end Smart Array controllers use). I would suggest [**updating the driver for your system**](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5269386&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D4103%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#Driver%20-%20Storage%20Controller), as that's the cause of the message flood.

Comment: Thx for your answer this will solve my problem, but do you know what this mean?

Answer (score 0):

As ewwhite wrote the problem is an old driver, to update your Dynamic Smart Array Driver try this:

In centos add a new repo, add following file: `/etc/yum.repos.d/HP-SPP.repo` with this content:

```
 [HP-SPP]
name=HP Software Delivery Repository for SPP
baseurl=http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/SPP/RHEL/$releasever/$basearch/current
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Now you can update with yum update and the message log will be clean.

Comment: I posted the link to the individual RPM file in my answer. That's a safer approach to installing the new driver.

Comment: Thx I add this Answer as follow answer, when anyone search for this problem he can resolve it without following any links.