# Which type of RAM we should use? Registered or Unregistered?

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

We are planning to buy two different servers from HP.  They will be used in project where we do lot of statistical analysis and Java development/testing etc.
Servers are :

a) Part :ML350e 2403 CTO
Model : HP ProLiant ML350e Gen8

b)Part No. 737650-375
Model : HP ProLiant ML10

RAM Models considered as per availability :
a) 8GB  Single Module    Part No : 647897-b21
b) 16 GB Single Module    Part NO: 647901-b21
(I believe both are registered ones)

Operating system:
Testing Phase 1: Windows Server 2008
Testing Phase 2 : Centos (whichever latest ed. available)

Should we go for Registered type or Unregistered?

Comment: How much RAM will you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your platform, the difference between UDIMMs and RDIMMs is price (lower), performance (lower) and maximum capacity (lower). Both UDIMMs and RDIMMs are supported just fine, but *cannot* be mixed.

```
Maximum (RDIMM) 192 GB (12 x 16 GB) RDIMM
Maximum (UDIMM) 96 GB (12 x 8 GB) UDIMM
```

Given a choice, I don't buy UDIMMs unless I know the system will have low RAM requirements. It really comes down to knowing there are more restrictions on UDIMMs and that I'd be making a compromise. The gap between them has narrowed in the current generation of servers, so both seem to be options.

I would strongly suggest that you give the [**ML350p Gen8**](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=5177961#!tab=features) a look, though. The HP Dynamic Smart Array included on the lower-end [**ML350e Gen8**](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=5260584#!tab=specs) servers will cause you trouble in the long-run, especially if you [intend to use this system with Linux](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/118133).

See:

[What "PAL Shim AllocRequest returning NULL" meens?](https://serverfault.com/questions/560132/what-pal-shim-allocrequest-returning-null-meens)

[Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on HP Proliant DL380e with 1TB SAS Drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/526111/installing-ubuntu-12-04-on-hp-proliant-dl380e-with-1tb-sas-drive/526227#526227)

[Install Oracle Linux 6.4 on HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 server](https://serverfault.com/questions/562574/install-oracle-linux-6-4-on-hp-proliant-dl380e-gen8-server/562576#562576)

[Poor SQL performance on HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 v2 with raid10](https://serverfault.com/questions/568313/poor-sql-performance-on-hp-proliant-ml310e-gen8-v2-with-raid10/568388#568388)

Answer (score 2):

Go with registered memory, anything else is a compromise, plus that model can only take 96GB of UDIMMs whereas it can take double that of RDIMMs.